# using _< instead of < for stdin using bash

Tags: bash, stdin

What is the difference between using `_<` and `<` for stdin when using process substitution.  This is done using bash.

Example:

```
read bytes _< <(du -bcm random_iso.iso | tail -1); echo $bytes
```

Comment: be careful with things like this when using a DEBUG trap, it will cause the meaning to change

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's not a `_<` operator, that's a `_` argument to pass to read and the `<` redirection operator. `<(cmd)` itself is process substitution (that expands to a filename that points to a pipe).

What that does is run:

```
read bytes _  < /proc/self/fd/x
```

Where the fd x is the reading end of a pipe.

At the other (writing) end of the pipe, a background subshell process is executing `du -bcm random_iso.iso | tail -1` with its stdout redirected to that pipe.

So `read` will store in the `$bytes` variable the first word of the last line of the output of `du -bcm`, and the rest of the line in the `$_` variable.

Now I don't know where that `du -bcm` makes sense. None of `-b`, `-c` nor `-m` options are standard. While `-c` is quite common and is for giving the cumulative size, with GNU `du`, `-b` is to get the file size (not disk usage) in bytes, while `-m` is to get the size rounded up to the next mebibyte so they would be conflicting options (though maybe they used `-b` for its side-effect of enabling `--apparent-size`). FreeBSD du has `-m` (for mebibytes), no `-b`, Solaris has neither...

It looks like it was meant as a convoluted way to write:

```
wc -c < random_iso.iso
```

Or:

```
du --apparent-size -cm random_iso.iso | awk 'END{print $1}'
```

If they indeed wanted the file size rounded up to the next mebibyte on a GNU system.

Comment: The command is used at 26:44 in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CQ6kD48WMxc#t=26m44s - I believe they were just looking to get the size of the iso in MB.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned, `_<` isn't a redirect. This is passing `_` as the final argument to `read`. The `<` is then interpreted as a separate redirect operator redirecting the process substitution's output to stdin.

It has become conventional in Bash scripts to use `_` as a "throwaway variable" in conjunction with the `read` builtin. In bash, `_` is a special variable that gets set to the final argument of a command after each command is executed. In this case, it means `bytes` will be assigned the first field, and the remaining fields are discarded into the `_` variable, instead of assigning all remaining fields into `bytes`.

While this is a convention, there are a number of good reasons to avoid abusing `_` in this way.

- This behavior of `_` is not specified by POSIX. Most shells won't do anything special with it.
- In `zsh`, `_` has the `readonly` attribute, and using this will cause the shell to throw an error.
- In `mksh`, `_` only has bash's behavior in interactive mode. In a non-interactive script, `_` is used for a different purpose and isn't assigned anything after each command.
- in `ksh93`, `_` is only set to the last argument of the last command on a line. Commands must be physically located on separate lines of code in order to make use of `_`. Additionally, `_` in ksh93 is overloaded to have many many other uses in various contexts, so assigning to `_` for this purpose isn't recommended and will do different things depending on context.

I recommend putting a space before a redirect to make things clearer. I put some guidelines on good redirect style in [this article](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial#a_note_on_style).